# How to correct this PowerShell script that auto deletes Sharepoint backups

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I've [been using this](http://imperfectit.blogspot.com/2010/03/automate-sharepoint-2010-farm-backups.html) ([and this](http://blog.wauwwie.nl/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=4)) script to delete older sharepoint backups, but it deletes all backups rather than the 14+ day old ones.

I ran it through powershell_ise.exe and put a break point under the line that has `$_.SPStartTime` in it, and it shows `$_.SPStartTime =` as if the date isn't populated. I looked inside `$sp.SPBackupRestoreHistory.SPHistoryObject` and that contains the data I expect.

The part that is there issue is on this line:

```
# Find the old backups in spbrtoc.xml
$old = $sp.SPBackupRestoreHistory.SPHistoryObject |
? { $_.SPStartTime -lt ((get-date).adddays(-$days)) }
```

I get all of the dates output (which I would expect). This tells me the problem in in the 'where' or '?' - I understand they are interchangeable. Regardless, $old always appears to be null.

As Requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SPBackupRestoreHistory>
    <SPHistoryObject>
        <SPId>a8a03c50-6bc2-4af4-87b3-caf60e750fa0</SPId>
        <SPRequestedBy>ASERVER\AUSER</SPRequestedBy>
        <SPBackupMethod>Full</SPBackupMethod>
        <SPRestoreMethod>None</SPRestoreMethod>
        <SPStartTime>01/09/2011 00:00:13</SPStartTime>
        <SPFinishTime>01/09/2011 00:05:22</SPFinishTime>
        <SPIsBackup>True</SPIsBackup>
        <SPConfigurationOnly>False</SPConfigurationOnly>
        <SPBackupDirectory>E:\Backups\spbr0003\</SPBackupDirectory>
        <SPDirectoryName>spbr0003</SPDirectoryName>
        <SPDirectoryNumber>3</SPDirectoryNumber>
        <SPTopComponent>Farm</SPTopComponent>
        <SPTopComponentId>689d7f0b-4f64-45d4-ac58-7ab225223625</SPTopComponentId>
        <SPWarningCount>0</SPWarningCount>
        <SPErrorCount>0</SPErrorCount>
    </SPHistoryObject>
    <SPHistoryObject>
        <SPId>22dace04-c300-41d0-a9f1-7cfe638809ef</SPId>
        <SPRequestedBy>ASERVER\AUSER</SPRequestedBy>
        <SPBackupMethod>Full</SPBackupMethod>
        <SPRestoreMethod>None</SPRestoreMethod>
        <SPStartTime>01/08/2011 00:00:13</SPStartTime>
        <SPFinishTime>01/08/2011 00:05:26</SPFinishTime>
        <SPIsBackup>True</SPIsBackup>
        <SPConfigurationOnly>False</SPConfigurationOnly>
        <SPBackupDirectory>E:\Backups\spbr0002\</SPBackupDirectory>
        <SPDirectoryName>spbr0002</SPDirectoryName>
        <SPDirectoryNumber>2</SPDirectoryNumber>
        <SPTopComponent>Farm</SPTopComponent>
        <SPTopComponentId>689d7f0b-4f64-45d4-ac58-7ab225223625</SPTopComponentId>
        <SPWarningCount>0</SPWarningCount>
        <SPErrorCount>0</SPErrorCount>
    </SPHistoryObject>
</SPBackupRestoreHistory>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like you're ending up with the comparison being string-based, rather than date-based, so for example:

```
"10/08/2007 20:20:13" -lt (Get-Date -Year 1900)
```

The number is always going to be less than the "Sunday" or "Monday" or whatever that you would get at the front of the string when the DateTime object is cast to a string ...

I don't have access to a set of backups I could test this on, but for starters, you should fix that, and at the same time, make sure that you're not deleting the backup just because the value is null:

```
# Find the old backups in spbrtoc.xml
$old = $sp.SPBackupRestoreHistory.SPHistoryObject |
Where { (Get-Date $_.SPStartTime) -lt ((get-date).adddays(-$days)) }
```

The date string format in the XML file (according to [the docs page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.backup.spbackuprestorehistorylist%28office.12%29.aspx)) is one that Get-Date can readily parse, so that should work without any problems.

Incidentally, your assumption is right about $_ being the current iteration object from the array ;)

Comment: I'll have a look into this, but what your saying makes sense... surprised no one else noticed this on their blogs.

Comment: See updated question - I think the problem is with the filtering as $old is always null

Comment: Can you post an example XML file? I'm perplexed :)

Comment: note I've been playing with the number of days I want to delete from and am aware there arn't 14 days previous - I've tried 1, 2 and 3 days so it should work

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've added an answer on how to do this, but given you the accept points

Answer (score 6):

I believe the issue was to do with the date formatting.

Final working script:

```
# Location of spbrtoc.xml
$spbrtoc = "E:\Backups\spbrtoc.xml" 

# Days of backup that will be remaining after backup cleanup.
$days = 14

# Import the Sharepoint backup report xml file
[xml]$sp = gc $spbrtoc 

# Find the old backups in spbrtoc.xml
$old = $sp.SPBackupRestoreHistory.SPHistoryObject |
    ? { ( (
             [datetime]::ParseExact($_.SPStartTime, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
          ) -lt (get-date).adddays(-$days)
        )
      }

if ($old -eq $Null) { write-host "No reports of backups older than $days days found in spbrtoc.xml.`nspbrtoc.xml isn't changed and no files are removed.`n" ; break} 

# Delete the old backups from the Sharepoint backup report xml file
$old | % { $sp.SPBackupRestoreHistory.RemoveChild($_) } 

# Delete the physical folders in which the old backups were located
$old | % { Remove-Item $_.SPBackupDirectory -Recurse } 

# Save the new Sharepoint backup report xml file
$sp.Save($spbrtoc)
Write-host "Backup(s) entries older than $days days are removed from spbrtoc.xml and harddisc."
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this! I had a few servers start deleting everything, maybe since the new year. This seems to keep the files around properly.